# How to send ISO format date from android to backend?

Tags: android, android-date

I am building an app where I am using date and time. I have to send time and time in ISO format. I am currently sending time like this:

```
 calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String time = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
```

What should I change to send ISO format of time?

EDIT: This is error on my backend:

```
Invalid format: "2016-08-30T13:54:22Z" is malformed at "Z"
```

Comment: See [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: What are you using to send the date to the backend?

Comment: give an example of `ISO format of time`

Comment: your format looks fine to me, is there any issue which I am missing out?

Comment: @himanshu1496 Well the problem is that my backend can't parse this type of time which I am sending...

Comment: @PedroAGSantos I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging for sending time and date to mu backend

Answer (score 0):

I am using the [date-format-iso8601](https://github.com/nobuoka/java-date-format-iso8601) library. It is very helpful.

Usage:

```
DateFormat f = new Iso8601ExtendedOffsetDateTimeFormat();
String date = f.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
long dateMillis = f.parse("date-string").getTime();
```